# Divi Builder Editor not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Anybody ever have a problem with DIVI Builder, where the entire editor module does not show when you try and edit a page?

It just shows me the below

[image: Page editor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clear Browser Cache/Cookies
2. I found that by placing this code to your .htaccess will resolve the particular limit on Apache Service.

```html
< IfModule mod_substitute.c >
SubstituteMaxLineLength 10M
< /IfModule >
```

(Make sure you remove the spaces on the < > tag )

- Increase WordPress Memory Limit on your hosting
- To address memory limit issues, there are two paths:
- Adjust it yourself or Contact your hosting company
- FTP to your web hosting and edit your wp-config.php file

```html
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

Comment: Hi, I have already increased the memory limit but that's not doing the trick so I'll try the htaccess work around but with this, do I add `< IfModule mod_substitute.c >
SubstituteMaxLineLength 10M
< /IfModule >`, directly underneath the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`?

Comment: yes it vil help but keep a backup of .htaccess file

Comment: I found that the problem is YOAST SEO plugin somehow clashing with the divi theme

Comment: it's version 7.6

Comment: deactive and activate plugin after changing .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

Just had almost the same issue. Fixed by installing Divi Tweaker plugin and enabled "Display Clear Divi Local Storage Button" and "Enable Divi Builder on Custom Post Types". Hope this makes someone's life easier.